# What type of visa do I need?

Tags: united-kingdom

My husband has an EEA passport and he currently has a permanent job in the UK. I would like to join him with our kids, but we do not have EEA citizenship. 
What kind of visa do I need (and for our kids) as well as what kind of documents do I use to apply for it?

Comment: What is the nationality of you and your kids?  What is your husbands annual income?

Comment: Depending on your nationalities and your husband’s circumstances in the UK, you can apply for a Family Permit https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility

Comment: @gerrit annual income does not matter if the principal is a national of an EEA country (and the family moves before the UK leaves the EU).  The fact that he has a job is sufficient.

Comment: @Traveller that sounds like an answer (though it doesn't depend on the family member's nationalities beyond their not being EEA nationals, which was already given in the question; the husband's circumstances as given are also sufficient, since a permanent job means he is "working" and therefore a [qualified person](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/documents-you-must-provide)).

Comment: @phoog A friend living in the London area cannot have his American wife move over, because he does not earn enough. His passport is British.

Comment: @gerrit that only applies to British citizens wanting to bring their family members.  British citizens are not "EEA nationals" under UK law except under certain limited circumstances.  In any case the nationality of the family members is not relevant unless they are EEA nationals, which we already know OP and her children are not.  If the *husband's* nationality is British, then the question needs to be updated because the answer would be radically different.

Comment: @phoog Are you saying a German (or other non-UK EEA) in the UK can more easily get a non-EEA spouse to join than a Brit in the UK?  That's... quite weird, but if true, I stand corrected.

Comment: @gerrit It’s true. One of the many reasons for the Brexit debacle, maybe :-)

Comment: @gerrit it is indeed true.  It's so true that some UK citizens have moved to the EU so as to trigger the circumstances allowing them to bring their family to the UK under the EU rules (search for "Surinder Singh"). Moving to Ireland and back is easier for some than sponsoring a family member. It is one aspect of EU regulation that was used to promote Brexit (i.e., "regain control of immigration"). Check Traveler's link above, and compare with https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa.  No thousands of pounds in fees, no income requirement.  Just freedom of movement.

Comment: @gerrit.  It's not just true in the UK.  *Most* EU countries have stricter rules for their own nationals bringing non-EEA partners than the EU regulations impose for non-nationals.  Of course, the difference is particularly stark for the UK because the rules are so onerous.

Answer (score 2):

As non-EEA family members of an EEA citizen already in the UK and working, you can apply for an EEA Family Permit https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eligibility.